# Searching for mp3 files on Google

Tags: google-search, mp3

Is there any way to search for mp3 files on Google? I mean the results should be only mp3 files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the `filetype:` search operator. Otherwise, as per [this Lifehacker article](http://lifehacker.com/339474/top-10-obscure-google-search-tricks), you could try something like this:

```
-inurl:(htm|html|php) in title:"index of" +"last modified" +"parent directory" +description +size +mp3 "Nirvana"
```