# Searching for video format like searching for mp3

Tags: google-search

Based on [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/65328/searching-for-mp3-files-on-google), I can use this:

```
-inurl:(htm|html|php) in title:"index of" +"last modified" +"parent directory" +description +size +mp3 "name_of_what_I_am_looking_for"
```

To search for all mp3 files. So how can I modify that search to look for mp4 or other video file formats?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
filetype:mp4
```

Or:

```
-inurl:(htm|html|php) in title:"index of" +"last modified" +"parent directory" +description +size +(mp4|avi|mkv) "name_of_what_I_am_looking_for"
```

Where you can put whatever other extension you are looking for instead of `+(mp4|avi|mkv)`, like this:

- just mp4: `+mp4`
- some other formats: `+(m4v|mov)`

Comment: thanks and yes I know to change the type. but the problem is when you looking for that on the search. you will see most ( or all )  of the result are mp3

Comment: @lion, try the first option then, like this: `what_you_are_searching_for filetype:mp4`